# Laravel/Eloquent get all appointments from a polymorphic "member_id" through a appointment_members table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, polymorphism, laravel-5.4

I have an `appointments` table and an `appointment_members` table and my users need to be able to get a collection of `appointments` by searching with a `"member_id"`, which could be a `Person`, `Incident` or `CustomerID`. The `appointment_members` table has `member_id` and `appointment_id` columns, so the `member_type` (also a column) is irrelevant. This all set up by a previous dev and what is missing are the relationships on the Eloquent models. I'm just creating a simple GET route that needs to return any/all appointments by that member_id. Each row has one appointment, so if I were to pass in a `member_id` that returned 10 results, some could have appts and others not, but at the end of the day I just need a collection of appts that are related to that `member_id`. Here's a screenshot of the `appointment_members` table:
[image]

If I create a simple `hasOne` relationship to appointments on appointment_members:

```
public function appointments()
{
    return $this->HasOne(Appointment::class, 'id', 'appointment_id');
}
```

I can get a collection of `appointment_members` with it's respective `appointment`, but not sure how I boil it down to just getting the `appointments`. One workaround I have is to use that HasOne and then pluck/filter the appointments:

```
$appointmentMembers = AppointmentMembers::where('member_id', $request->input('memberId'))->get();
$appointments = $appointmentMembers->pluck('appointments')->filter();
```

Curious if anyone might see a better way to go about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm possibly not understanding, but I would probably take the simplest approach here if the member type is not important.

The table is already set up to handle either a belongsToMany or a morphMany, so create the relationship on the Member class (or if you don't have a parent member class, stick it on each of the types Person, Incident, etc.  You can also do this via poly, of course, but this is a simple example to get what you need):

```
public function appointments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Appointment::class)->withPivot('member_type');
}
```

And then just query on the member object you need appointments for (having poly would make this one step):

```
$allAppointmentsForID = $member->appointments();
$appointments = $allAppointmentsForID->wherePivot('member_type', $whateverClassThisIS);
```

The above takes member_type into account.  If this doesn't matter, you can just use the top line.

Your original db is setup to handle polymorphic relations, so if you wanted more than the appointment you can set it up this way as well.  For now, you'll need to add the TYPE to the query to cover the different classes.

If the member type is important, polymorphic might be something like this on the Member class:

```
public function appointments()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Appointment::class, 'memberableOrmember_typeOrWhatever');
}
```

Then you can query on the member object with just one line

```
$appointments = $member->appointments();
```